# AngularJs : $http chaining

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have these two functions and this is a sample of code

```
var getRangeTime = function(numSerie){
      $http.get("data/tempsgammes.json").then(function(res){
          return $scope.time = res.data[numSerie].temps
    })}

var updateScreen = function() {
      $http.get("http://localhost:5000").then(function(response){
        $scope.numSerie = response.data.refDetail.Num_Serie
        $scope.numTeam = response.data.team
        $scope.t = getRangeTime($scope.numSerie)
        //Rest of code the code
    }
```

Here what I want to do :

First of all, I call the function **updateScreen()** to get the Serial Number **(numSerie)**, then depending on the value of **numSerie**, another function **getRangeTime()** will be exectued to get the time, and then the function **updateScreen()** will continue her execution using the result of **getRangeTime()**.

The problem here is the asynchronous, I mean the **updateSreen()** should wait **getRangeTime()** until she returns the desired value, it's kind of **async** and **await**.

I've tried it but it didn't work and actually I don't know how to use them very much, I searched here and I tried the existing solutions but it didn't go well too, I got always the **undefined**.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late here but you can also use callbacks(I haven't tested this but it should work):

```
var updateScreen = function(callback) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:5000").then(function(response){
        $scope.numSerie = response.data.refDetail.Num_Serie
        $scope.numTeam = response.data.team
        $scope.t = getRangeTime($scope.numSerie)
        callback($scope.numSerie);
    }
}

updateScreen(function(numSerie) {
   $http.get("data/tempsgammes.json").then(function(res){
          return $scope.time = res.data[numSerie].temps
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I tried the solution provided by @Sajeetharan and it works.I'll try yours in another time.
But I have a question related to "Sajeetharan" if you can answer it, after calling return getRangeTime(); I complete the rest of the code in the second response, isn't it ?

Comment: @AnesElGongi Yes, by the looks of it, that would be my understanding as well.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should use promise chains to call the request one after the other.

```
function updateScreen(){
    return $http.get("http://localhost:5000")
}

function getRangeTime(){
   return  $http.get("data/tempsgammes.json")
}

$scope.calltwoFunctions = function() {
     updateScreen()
       .then( function( response )
        {
            $scope.numSerie = response.data.refDetail.Num_Serie
            $scope.numTeam = response.data.team
            return getRangeTime();
        })
        .then(function(response){
           console.log(response.data);
        })
}
```

Comment: okay thank you so much, i'll try it and then I will comment another time.